# Changes are lost after editing <hostname>.xml by virsh edit command

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, xen

I am using 'virsh edit' command to edit an XML of the host. As soon as I add the contents I come out of the file by: wq!(vi editor style), Again I entered 'virsh edit' command and found my edits in the XML are lost. I checked the permissions in /etc/libvirt/qemu and found the permissions are rw-----, I was editing the file as root.

Could anyone help what can be the issue?

Comment: why are you using `:q` with `!`? maybe when you use `:w` alone you can see an error message.